# Extjs Grid - Customize empty/undefined cell

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid which displays data from database, sometimes some cells are empty because there is no data in that column in database. and sometimes the data is "undefined". So I need to show this text "No Data" in these two cases in the grid. I read that I can do it with the renderer but still can't figure out how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply a renderer to that gridcolumn like

```
renderer: function(val) {
    if (val === null || val === undefined)
        return 'No Data';
    return val;
}
```

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2hBm/)**

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH SRA !! I really appreciate you efforts here!!